# Баг в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Я уверен проблема распространенная, но её решение я не нашел. Я использую Android Studio. Когда сворачиваю студию путём alt+tab, то в студии вылетает много ошибок типа "error saving system information.....", которые приходится постоянно закрывать. Очень сильно раздражает этот баг, как его исправить?

Comment: Постоянно только так и делаю. Ошибок не замечал.
Пробовали официальный `issues` подобный найти? Попробуйте переустановить студию вместе с SDK и JDK.

Comment: @whalemare пробовал, не помогает. На работу приложения никак не влияет, но постоянно закрывать всплывающие сообщения как-то надоедает..